# Function pause() on a video doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop and switch video when I click on a link.

I've try this : $($old_media)[0].pause();

But this line doesn't work and my js file doesn't work anymore too.

I have include JQuery lib from Google but it said that pause() is not a function.

Someone has a solution please?

Here is my js code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $.current_selected = $("#first_selected").html();
        $("[id^='feature-href-']").click(function()
            {
                $use_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("feature-href-", "");

                $old_header = "#feature-node-header-"+$.current_selected;
                $old_media = "#feature-node-media-"+$.current_selected;
                $header_id = "#feature-node-header-"+$use_id;
                $media_id = "#feature-node-media-"+$use_id;

                $("#feature-media-container").slideUp("slow");
                $($media_id+" > object").addClass("no_display");

                /* Clear old header */
                $($old_media)[0].pause();
                $($old_header).addClass("no_display");
                $($header_id).removeClass("no_display");

                /* Hide old Media*/
                $($old_media).slideUp("slow");
                $($old_media+" object").addClass("no_display");

                setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        $("#feature-media-container").slideDown("fast");
                        setTimeout(function()
                            {   
                                $($media_id).slideDown("slow");     
                                $($media_id+" > object").removeClass("no_display");
                            }
                        ,1000);
                    }
                ,150);
                $.current_selected = $use_id;
                return false;
            });
    });
```

Comment: Does `console.log($($old_media)[0])` show a `<video>` element? Does `console.log($old_media)` show the selector that you expect? This is basic debugging.

Comment: As a sidenote, all your variables are global, and you're adding random HTML to the global `jQuery` object when you do `$.something = ...`

Comment: It show's  a <div> element wich is around a <video> element.

Comment: Thanks for solutions, my problem is resolved :)